# How do I bind columns of a parent row to a set of child objects in of an ultrawingrid?

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Suppose I have a data set that contains orders where every order contains one or more order items. So if I have an order with two orders, where order #1 has three items (A,B,C) and order #2 had two items (D,E), I want to see something like this:

<kbd>Order #</kbd><kbd>Contact Name</kbd><kbd>Item</kbd><kbd>Item</kbd><kbd>Item</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Jim Bob</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Albert</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>

This kicker is that I do not know how many items there are ahead of time, and that I would like each cell to be editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few possible options to solve this task. Maybe the easiest could be if you are using   DataSet and two DataTables (one for your Orders and second one for your Order`s Items). After that you could create a DataRelation between both tables and apply this DataSet to DataSource property of your grid.

Another possible solution could be if you are using GroupByColumn functionality of our grid. Using this approach you could group by your Orders column

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Georgi is correct in his answer. Sorry for the long delay, but the project got dropped and then reopened. Part of the problem here is that we are working with a much older version of ideablade/infragistics for this particular project which causes confusion when viewing newer documentation online.

In addition to his suggestions I would point out that the question is too broad and depends on the way the DataGrid is being bound. If DataTables are not an option then inserting unbound columns and managing the data your self, or using an UltraDataSource are also options.